# How to find the type of ICommandHandler<SignUpCommand> interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, dependency-injection, reflection

I have some commands and command handlers like this:

```
>> public abstract class Command {}

>> public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand: Command {}

>> public class SignUpCommand: Command {}

>> public class SignUpCommandHandler<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : SignUpCommand {}
```

I need to register the handlers in the DI container. I can do it manually, one by one, and it works fine:

```
services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<SignUpCommand>, SignUpCommandHandler<SignUpCommand>>();
```

But I want to change my code so that it gets all from the assembly. So I need to change the above code to this:

```
var allCustomerCommandHandlers = System.Reflection.Assembly
    .GetAssembly(typeof(SignUpCommandHandler<SignUpCommand>))
    .GetTypes().Where(t =>
    { 
        return t.Name.Contains("CommandHandler");
    }).ToList();
foreach (var commandHandler in allCustomerCommandHandlers)
{
    services.AddScoped(commandHandler.GetInterfaces()[0], commandHandler);
}
```

The problem is here: `commandHandler.GetInterfaces()[0]`

The interface of my class does not load completely. Assembly reflection doesn't give all data of type interface by `GetInterfaces()[0]` itself or the `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` method of that.

By using `GetGenericTypeDefinition()`, all types are registered successfully but while injecting I get this error:

> GenericArguments[0], 'Customers.SignUpCommand', on
> 'Customers.UpdateScoreCommandHandler`1[TCommand]' violates the
> constraint of type 'TCommand'.'

and if I use `GetInterfaces()[0]` directly, I get this error while registration:

> Cannot instantiate implementation type
> 'Siamak.Shop.CustomerContext.Application.Customers.AddAddressCommandHandler`1[TCommand]' for service type 'Siamak.Shop.Framework.Application.ICommandHandler`1[TCommand]'.'

It seems that the problem is the `GetInterfaces` method if we get it from the assembly reflection APIs. If we check the interface definition directly(`typeof(ICommandHandler<SignUpCommand>)`) it is like this:

[image]

And also If we check the data of `typeof(SignUpCommandHandler<SignUpCommand>).GetInterfaces()[0]` directly(Not using the reflection) it gives all data too and works fine in one-by-one registration

[image]

But for `GetInterfaces()[0]` **coming from the reflection APIs** as you can see most of its data is null. Like FullName:

[image]

So has anybody any suggestion for this? Or a better way to register my classes(Using .Net core APIs):

**Note**: I have used libraries like Castle Windsor before but I want to do it in .Net Core 7 natively if possible.

Comment: But I am trying to handle it using pure .Net APIs and not using 3rd parties. It is a common problem and I think .Net can support it

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nugget package called Scrutor:

```
 services.Scan(x => x.FromAssemblies(your_assembly)
        .AddClasses(c => c.AssignableTo(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .WithScopedLifetime());
```

Edit: Without Scrutor

```
  foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=>!x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract && x.GetInterfaces().Any(y=>y.IsGenericType && y.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>))))
    {
        var @interface = type.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>)).First();
       
        services.AddScoped(@interface, type); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @spyros__ . I want to do this with .Net Core's native APIs. Previously I was using Castle Windsor and it works fine for me.

Comment: You're welcome. I have implement a mediator as well, if you want to get any ideas https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q93pK9LZ5Qk